# 3D polygon in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, 3d, polygon

Is there a 3D polygon in JavaFX (similar to QuadArray in Java3D)?
If there isn't what is the simplest way to create one? Creating two triangles?
If there is no simple way than should I use 3rd party 3D library? But that would beat the idea of using JavaFX in the first place.

I would like the abbility to switch between faces, wire-mode and verts-only-mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update 2024

This entire original answer and the techniques in it are obsolete, plus the links it provides are no longer active (which doesn't matter because the information in the links is also obsolete).

[JavaFX added 3D support over a decade ago](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm), after this answer was created.  For basic 3D work using JavaFX, the built-in JavaFX 3D libraries are what should be used.  The linked tutorial demonstrates 3D polygon display in JavaFX.

Third party libraries such as [FXyz](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz) add additional capability to the support for 3D in the core JavaFX library.

There are [integrations with jogl](https://forum.jogamp.org/Jogl-and-JavaFX-td4040468.html) if the core 3D support in JavaFX does not suffice.

#### Original early 2013 answer

3D in JavaFX 2.x is pretty limited.

You can create a 3D polygon by creating a 2D polygon and performing a transform on it.

There are some [3D samples in the Ensemble application](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html) which demonstrate how to do this (with source code).  There is a [simple cube sample here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2480840&tstart=0).

With JavaFX 2.x, you could implement switches between face view, wireframe view and vertex only view with little difficulty.  Other things like complex lighting, effects, mesh loading, realistic shading etc, would be more difficult and would be better implemented in JavaFX 8.

JavaFX 8 will have a much more robust and useful 3D implementation.  You should evaluate the capabilities of the current JavaFX 3D demos in Ensemble as well as the [proposed JavaFX 8 3D feature set](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/3D+Features) against your requirements and other 3D libraries such as [lwjgl](http://www.lwjgl.org) to determine what will best fit your needs.  Note, JavaFX 8 is not scheduled for final release until September 2013.  Over time the proposed JavaFX 8 3D features will be added to the [Java 8 pre-release](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

I did create a simple 3D software renderer for a JavaFX `ImageView` which I might open source if interested - it renders bitmaps onto an `ImageView` though - not directly to the JavaFX scene graph primitives.  A similar thing, but using a hardware renderer via the Java3D API was created by [Interactive Mesh](http://www.interactivemesh.org/testspace/j3dmeetsjfx.html).  Unlike JavaFX 8, it has the advantage of being available today.

Comment: Thank you. I already wrote code for creating polygons models in Java3D so I guess I'll reuse it. I'm only interested in CAD-like view, without shadows and bitmaps, but thank you for your offer. JavaFX 8 3D features looks really promising, but too bad it's scheduled so late.

Comment: Link "simple cube sample here" is dead.

Comment: @SamGinrich the entire answer and the techniques in it is obsolete.  JavaFX [added 3D support over a decade ago](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm), after this answer was created, 3rd party libraries such as [FXyz](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz) add additional capability to the support for 3D in the core JavaFX library.

Answer (score 0):

Interoperability between JavaFX 2 and the main sets of Java bindings for low level 3D APIs ([JogAmp](http://jogamp.org/) and its main competitor quoted by jewelsea) is already partially implemented. When it is ready, you will be able to use the very latest version of Java3D (1.6.0, the instructions to install it are [here](http://tinyurl.com/cf47kcb)) or any scenegraph supporting JOGL 2.0 including Ardor3D, JMonkeyEngine 3, Xith3D, ... There are already some applications mixing JOGL 2 and JavaFX in the same window but not in the same panel, for example Energy3D.

Answer (score 0):

https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/3D+Features

JavaFX 8 includes a full 3D library.  I currently am working with it, but it can be buggy + it's not even fully ready for dev's yet, or even close for the general release.